# WCF-Communication with multiple endpoints

Tags: c#, wcf, config, endpoints

I have a problem. I try to build a WCF Communication with multiple entpoints. But it never works and it displays a ErrorMessage like this:

- The contract name '{0}' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service '{1}'.

And this is my Config-File:

*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MwWcfLibrary.Service">

        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8733" 
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration=""
                  bindingName="Action"
                  name="ActionInterface" 
                  contract="MwWcfLibrary.Actions.Interfaces.IAction">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration=""
                  name="Mex"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding"
                  address="net.tcp://localhost:8733"
                  bindingConfiguration=""
                  name="LifeSignInterface"
                  bindingName="LifeSign"
                  contract="MwWcfLibrary.LifeSign.Interfaces.ILifeSign" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding"
                  address="net.tcp://localhost:8733"
                  bindingConfiguration=""
                  name="DataInterface"
                  bindingName="Data"
                  contract="MwWcfLibrary.Notification.Interfaces.IData">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding"
                  address="net.tcp://localhost:8733"
                  bindingConfiguration=""
                  name="PublicDataInterface"
                  bindingName="PublicData"
                  contract="MwWcfLibrary.PublicData.Interfaces.IPublicData" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding"
                  address="net.tcp://localhost:8733"
                  bindingConfiguration=""
                  name="PublicStateInterface"
                  bindingName="PublicState"
                  contract="MwWcfLibrary.PublicState.Interfaces.IPublicState" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8733//MwWcfLibrary" />
          </baseAddresses>
          <timeouts closeTimeout="00:00:30" />
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

*

Does someone figure out if i configured something wrong?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

You either haven't implemented one of these interfaces:
`MwWcfLibrary.Actions.Interfaces.IAction`, `MwWcfLibrary.LifeSign.Interfaces.ILifeSign`, `MwWcfLibrary.PublicData.Interfaces.IPublicData` and `MwWcfLibrary.PublicState.Interfaces.IPublicState`

or one or more of them is not decorated with the `[ServiceContract]` attribute

Include the actual error in your question instead of '{0}', you'll see that some of your contracts have not been implemented by the class `Service` which should look like this (at least):

```
class Service : IAction, ILifeSign, IPublicData, IPublicState
{
  // implementation
}
```

Also, your address attributes don't appear to be correct, since you've defined a base address ending with a segment //Mww... yet in your endpoints the address is shorter than the base address. The endpoint addresses can just be relative like `"Service"`.

**Previously**

The `Service` element refers to a class that's an implementation of a `ServiceContract` interface, which is what goes into the `endpoint` contract attribute. Verify the fully qualified names of your interfaces and classes in theses attributes.

From looking at your configuration file, you are saying that the class `MwWcfLibrary.Service` implements the (`[ServiceContract]` decorated) interfaces called  `MwWcfLibrary.Actions.Interfaces.IAction`, `MwWcfLibrary.LifeSign.Interfaces.ILifeSign`, `MwWcfLibrary.PublicData.Interfaces.IPublicData` and `MwWcfLibrary.PublicState.Interfaces.IPublicState`

That seems to be in error. Do you mean to have two services, each with a separate endpoint?

Comment: Hello reckface.
Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: My intention is to have only one service with the listet interfaces.

Comment: you mean to implement all these interfaces in one class, and then use that as the service?

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what was missing in my code.